# Abstract definition of hypertoric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, toric-varieties

I'm reading Proudfoot's [survey on hypertoric varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4236). In Section 1.4 he mentioned such a conjecture:

> **Conjecture 1.4.2** Any connected, symplectic, algebraic variety which is projective over its affinization and admits an effective, hamiltonian action of the algebraic torus $T^d$ is equivariantly isomorphic to a Zariski open subset of a hypertoric variety.

Has this conjecture been proved or proved with some additional hypotheses?